# facebook strategy of passportjs is not passing data to next funtion

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, facebook-login

I am having a problem with passport Facebook strategy.
This is my route:

```
app.post('/auth/facebook',
    passport.authorize('facebook-token', {session: false}),
    socialAuths.fbAuth
);
```

This is passport code:

```
passport.use(new FacebookTokenStrategy({
    clientID: config.facebookAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.facebookAuth.clientSecret
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    return done(accessToken, profile);
}));
```

This is function that is supposed to be called after callback function of `passport.use`:

```
fbAuth(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.accessToken, req.profile);
};
```

but for me this function is not being called request ends at return `done(accessToken, profile);`
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it for me

```
return done(null, {accessToken, profile});
```

done funtion accepts fullowing parameters

Fisrt is an error 
Second is data that will attached to req object and accessible in next middlware
Third is an optional message